# Есть ли способ напечатать вращающийся курсор в терминале, используя Python?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать вращающийся курсор в терминале, что то типа такого: 10% *** курсор ----- 100%
Совет печати символа backspace (\b) между четырьмя символами, которые заставят "курсор" выглядеть как вращающийся (-, \, |, /) выдает тупо строку - \ / |/\ / |/\ / |/\ / |/\ / |/.

Comment: так стирать консоль же надо, вы просто выводите в ряд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
import time
from itertools import cycle, islice

for c in islice(cycle(['-', '/', '|', '\\']), 100):
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
```